# In Observer Design pattern, are Subject and Observable the same thing?

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, observable, subject

In Observer design pattern, the observer observes the subject and/or the observable. Observer gets notified by their updates.

I am confused whether those two things (subject and the observable) are essentially the same things? Or is there a subtle difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Observer Design Pattern can be used whenever a subject has to be observed by one or more observers.

**Observable** - interface or abstract class defining the operations for attaching and de-attaching observers to the client. In the GOF book this class/interface is known as **Subject**.

**They are essentially same.**

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, both are same.**

Subject is observable by observers.
Subject keeps a list of observers, so that it can notify these observers any state changes.

Check below Python code, taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

```
class Observable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__observers = []

    def register_observer(self, observer):
        self.__observers.append(observer)

    def notify_observers(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for observer in self.__observers:
            observer.notify(self, *args, **kwargs)


class Observer:
    def __init__(self, observable):
        observable.register_observer(self)

    def notify(self, observable, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Got', args, kwargs, 'From', observable)


subject = Observable()
observer = Observer(subject)
subject.notify_observers('test')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Subject and observer are two different entities(objects):

But with regards to your question,

> the observer observes the subject or the observable
>
> another name for subject would be observable, so they are same

Subject maintains a list of observers and all observers register at Subject.
So, whenever some event happens at subject, he notifies all observers.

> Example:

Say you have a class called HTTPEngine which handles all HTTP related stuff(connection,data retreival etc).

For HTTPEngine to be reusable across different objects, It maintains a list of say IHTTPObserver.

So, any object wishing to use HTTPEngine, implements interface HTTPObserver,  registers at HTTPEngine and then gets notified for events.

ex:

```
class HTTPObserver
{
 public:
 virtual void onEvent() = 0;

}
```

so, say a class by the name "client" wants to use HTTPENgine.

```
class client: public HTTPObserver
{
  void onEvent(){//got the event notification}
}
```

Now, HTTPENgine maintains a list of observers:

```
class HTTPEngine
{
private:
 vector<IHTTPObserver*> clients;
public:
 void register(IHTTPObserver* client){clients.push_back(client);} 
 void notifyclients(){
 for(it=vector.begin();it!=Vector.end();it++)
 (*it)->notifyEvent();}

};
```

Comment: I am more confused now because I have two different answers now :D

Comment: @HarisGhauri, I guess what basav was trying to tell was: Subject and observers are different, but your question was regarding: Whether Subject and Observable are same or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Observer design pattern is used when using an one-to-many relationship
>   and to update dependent objects if updated the main object.Observer
>   patter is an example for behavioral design patters. It has three
>   actors such main class, dependent super class and it's child classes.

**Look at following UML diagram of observer design pattern.**

[image]

1. The `Circle` class is the main class. It has a
   special property observers which keeps all observer of the circle. It can attach (or reattach if needed) observers.
2. The `Observer` class is super class of dependencies. It is an abstract class to provide common methods for `Circle` class.
3. Child observer classes (`AreaObserver` and `PerimeterObserver`) are the dependents of main class (`Circle`)
4. I used `ObserverExample` to test the example. It is not a content of Observer design pattern.

**Circle.java**

```
public class Circle {

    private List<Observer> observers;
    private double radius;

    public Circle() {
        observers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        notifyObservers();
    }

    /**
     * attach an observer to the circle
     */
    public void attach(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    /**
     * notify all observers on update
     */
    public void notifyObservers() {
        for (Observer observer : observers) {
            observer.update();
        }
    }
}
```

**Observer.java**

```
public abstract class Observer {

    protected Circle circle;

    public Observer(Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }

    public abstract void update();
}
```

**AreaObserver.java**

```
public class AreaObserver extends Observer {

    public AreaObserver(Circle circle) {
        super(circle);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        System.out.printf("New area is: %f\n", Math.PI * circle.getRadius() * circle.getRadius());
    }
}
```

**PerimeterObserver.java**

```
public class PerimeterObserver extends Observer {

    public PerimeterObserver(Circle circle) {
        super(circle);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        System.out.printf("New Perimeter is: %f\n", 2 * Math.PI * circle.getRadius());
    }
}
```

**ObserverExample.java**

```
public class ObserverExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle circle = new Circle();

        PerimeterObserver perimeterObserver = new PerimeterObserver(circle);
        circle.attach(perimeterObserver);

        AreaObserver areaObserver = new AreaObserver(circle);
        circle.attach(areaObserver);

        System.out.println("Set radius: 7.0");
        System.out.println("---------------");
        circle.setRadius(7.0);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Set radius: 5.0");
        System.out.println("---------------");
        circle.setRadius(5.0);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Set radius: 7.0
---------------
New Perimeter is: 43.982297
New area is: 153.938040

Set radius: 5.0
---------------
New Perimeter is: 31.415927
New area is: 78.539816
```

According to the output it seems all observers are updated when updating the main class.